# How inaccurate can the sys.dm_db_partition_stats.row_count be in getting an Azure SQL DB row count for each table?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, rowcount, sys.dm-sql

I have seen a number of general statements on how `sys.dm_db_partition_stats.row_count` can produce  inaccurate results due to providing objects' statistics instead of actually doing a `COUNT()`. However, I have never been able to find any deeper reasons behind those statements or validate the hypothesis on my Azure SQL DB.

So I would like to learn -

1. How inaccurate this method can  *actually*  be?
2. Why exactly the results might be skewed? 
    (e.g. stats are only recalculated once per day / on specific object operation).

Any related insight is much appreciated !

---

Several things I was able to find out on my own -- mostly by running various queries containing `sys.dm_db_partition_stats.row_count`, while knowing actual row counts in each table.

Here's a final **query** I came up with   
This gets fast and (in my case) accurate row count for each table, sorted from high count to low.

```sql
SELECT 
    (SCHEMA_NAME(A.schema_id) + '.' + A.Name) as table_name,  
    B.object_id, B.index_id, B.row_count 
FROM  
    sys.dm_db_partition_stats B 
LEFT JOIN 
    sys.objects A 
    ON A.object_id = B.object_id 
WHERE 
    SCHEMA_NAME(A.schema_id) <> 'sys' 
    AND (B.index_id = '0' OR B.index_id = '1') 
ORDER BY 
    B.row_count DESC
```

First line of `WHERE` clause is used to exclude system tables, e.g. `sys.plan_persist_wait_stats` and many others.

Second line takes care of non-unique non-clustered indexes (which are objects and apparently have their own stats)  ->  if you don't filter them out, you get double row count for indexed tables when using `GROUP BY A.schema_id, A.Name` or two records with the same `table_name` in the query output (if you don't use `GROUP BY`)

Comment: If you want to see how far off the numbers can be, I suggest you try doing user transactions, inserting a bunch of rows, then roll back the transaction.

Comment: Hi @Dima, you should post your new edit as an answer.

Comment: @Conor, thank you!  This actually helped me. In my case, the DB is not being updated more than a few times per day, so I can live with minor discrepancies stats.row_count can produce at some points in time.  Off-topic, I was rather pleased to see MS Architect comment on my question  :)   Thx for taking the time to do it

Comment: Note that the count can be wrong forever if you don't rebuild indexes and such.  It is approximate and can be perfectly correct, but it is not guaranteed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're glad that you found the solution and solved it by yourself. Your new edition should be an answer. I just help you post it as answer and this can be beneficial to other community members:

Several things I was able to find out on my own -- mostly by running various queries containing `sys.dm_db_partition_stats.row_count`, while knowing actual row counts in each table.

Here's a final query I came up with
This gets fast and (in my case) accurate row count for each table, sorted from high count to low.

```
SELECT 
    (SCHEMA_NAME(A.schema_id) + '.' + A.Name) as table_name,  
    B.object_id, B.index_id, B.row_count 
FROM  
    sys.dm_db_partition_stats B 
LEFT JOIN 
    sys.objects A 
    ON A.object_id = B.object_id 
WHERE 
    SCHEMA_NAME(A.schema_id) <> 'sys' 
    AND (B.index_id = '0' OR B.index_id = '1') 
ORDER BY 
    B.row_count DESC
```

First line of `WHERE` clause is used to exclude system tables, e.g. sys.plan_persist_wait_stats and many others.

Second line takes care of non-unique non-clustered indexes (which are objects and apparently have their own stats) -> if you don't filter them out, you get double row count for indexed tables when using `GROUP BY A.schema_id, A.Name` or two records with the same `table_name` in the query output (if you don't use `GROUP BY`)

Thanks for your sharing again.

And thanks for @conor's commnet: "If you want to see how far off the numbers can be, I suggest you try doing user transactions, inserting a bunch of rows, then roll back the transaction."

Comment: Thanks @Leon!  I was not sure which edit you mentioned, because, in fact, this was part of what I have posted within original question (just re-ordered the paragraphs to make it top-down).  Also, please, do include a comment from Conor -- to perform some user transactions, insert a bunch of rows, then roll back the transactions -- in order to determine the degree of inconsistency of stats.row_count